# Core Data Instruments for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data, instruments

I'm trying to monitor my core data usage but all the Core Data instruments are greyed out in Instruments. It's also not available from the "Run with Performance Tool" in Xcode. It says that the Core Data instruments are for the Mac and it's not available on the iPhone, but I've heard people talking about using it, and it's mentioned in the Apple docs too.

How can I get them working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can run Core Data instruments against the simulator only, not the device.

Open Instruments and select the Core Data items you want, then use Instruments to launch the simulated iPhone app, instead of launching from Xcode.

Hopefully this support is better in future versions. Also, I believe it only works with 3.1, not 3.0.

Comment: Ah got it working on the simulator! Thanks for that! I'm sure it wasn't working before, must have been playing up!

Comment: The Core Data instruments on the Mac rely on DTrace.  Since we don't have DTrace on the iPhone yet, I'm not surprised that they only work against the Simulator (like custom DTrace scripts do).

Comment: I get "Error starting script via dtrace server" for all Core Data instruments on Xcode 5/iOS Simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this still true today, almost 6 years later?

Comment: If you select an actual iPhone, you'll get a little yellow triangle that says "This device does not support this instrument". So yeah, still doesn't work :(

Comment: Still no support in xCode 6.4

Comment: Still true in XCode 9.4